# How can I always keep all YAXIS visible no matter if series are toggled

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, echarts

I have set up a **custom multiple YAXIS bar chart**, and I am trying to keep all the yaxis always visible, no matter if their related series have been hidden by clicking them on the legend.

One or more series can be attached to the same YAXIS.

[Initial YAXIS state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqyE0.png)

***Image 1 description:** initial state, where all YAXIS are perfectly rendered.*

As you can see in this second screenshot of my chart, if YAXIS are hidden when toggling series, those yaxis that should be kept are not properly displayed, since they are partially off canvas.

[Off-canvas YAXIS when toggling series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgfJ7.png)

***Image 2 description:** The name of the right "C.R." YAXIS has been placed off canvas.*

I know it is possible to keep them fix, since there is one of the ECHART's demo examples that demonstrate it (you may need to first add `legend: { show: true },` into the options object):

- https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=multiple-y-axis

I have also checked other demo examples in order to find any hint, but do not behave the same way. The following examples hide YAXIS when toggling the related series (this is the current behavior of my ECHART, which I am trying to avoid):

- https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-negative2
- https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-tick-align

The first one is the only valid example I have found that could help me.

I have been reading the whole documentation thoroughly. Even I've read carefully all the options from each of those three charts by clicking on the top-left tab `Full Code` and `Option preview` in order to find which is the difference.
But I still can not figure out which is the property that accomplishes to keep all YAXIS always visible. Or maybe it is the combination of two or more options working together.

**This is the whole options object I am implementing** (data arrays are truncated):

```
{
  "title": {
    "show": true,
    "text": "Demo title",
    "textStyle": {
      "color": "#000",
      "fontStyle": "normal",
      "fontWeight": "normal",
      "fontFamily": "sans-serif",
      "fontSize": 20,
      "lineHeight": 30
    },
    "subtext": "Demo subtitle",
    "subtextStyle": {
      "color": "#333",
      "fontStyle": "normal",
      "fontWeight": "normal",
      "fontFamily": "sans-serif",
      "fontSize": 14,
      "align": "left",
      "verticalAlign": "top",
      "lineHeight": 21
    },
    "textAlign": "left",
    "textVerticalAlign": "top",
    "padding": [
      0,
      0,
      20,
      0
    ],
    "itemGap": 0,
    "left": "auto",
    "top": "auto",
    "right": "auto",
    "bottom": "auto",
    "backgroundColor": "transparent"
  },
  "legend": {
    "type": "scroll",
    "show": true,
    "zlevel": 0,
    "z": 2,
    "left": "center",
    "top": "auto",
    "right": "auto",
    "bottom": 0,
    "width": "auto",
    "height": "auto",
    "orient": "horizontal",
    "align": "auto",
    "padding": [
      10,
      10
    ],
    "itemGap": 25,
    "itemWidth": 25,
    "itemHeight": 14,
    "symbolKeepAspect": true,
    "selectedMode": true,
    "inactiveColor": "#ccc",
    "textStyle": {
      "color": "#000",
      "fontSize": 14,
      "lineHeight": 21,
      "align": "left",
      "verticalAlign": "middle",
      "padding": 0
    },
    "tooltip": {
      "show": true
    },
    "icon": "circle",
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "borderRadius": 5,
    "scrollDataIndex": 0,
    "pageButtonItemGap": 27,
    "pageButtonGap": 25,
    "pageButtonPosition": "end",
    "pageFormatter": "{current} / {total}",
    "pageIconColor": "#0d47a1",
    "pageIconInactiveColor": "#aaa",
    "pageIconSize": 20,
    "pageTextStyle": {
      "fontSize": 14,
      "lineHeight": 21
    },
    "animation": false,
    "animationDurationUpdate": 800,
    "selector": [
      {
        "type": "all",
        "title": "All"
      },
      {
        "type": "inverse",
        "title": "Inverse"
      }
    ],
    "selectorLabel": {
      "show": true,
      "distance": 5,
      "rotate": 0,
      "offset": [
        0,
        0
      ],
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "fontSize": 16,
      "lineHeight": 24,
      "align": "center",
      "verticalAlign": "middle",
      "backgroundColor": "#0d47a1",
      "borderColor": "transparent",
      "borderWidth": 3,
      "borderRadius": 3,
      "padding": [
        7,
        10,
        4,
        10
      ]
    },
    "selectorPosition": "auto",
    "selectorItemGap": 10,
    "selectorButtonGap": 20
  },
  "grid": {
    "show": false,
    "left": 67,
    "top": 140,
    "right": 201,
    "bottom": 100,
    "width": "auto",
    "height": 490,
    "containLabel": true
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "show": true,
    "position": "bottom",
    "offset": 5,
    "type": "category",
    "nameLocation": "end",
    "nameGap": 25,
    "nameRotate": 0,
    "inverse": false,
    "boundaryGap": true,
    "axisLabel": {
      "show": true,
      "interval": "auto",
      "inside": false,
      "rotate": 45,
      "margin": 12,
      "showMinLabel": true,
      "showMaxLabel": true,
      "fontSize": 11,
      "lineHeight": 11,
      "align": "right"
    },
    "splitLine": {
      "show": false
    },
    "data": [
      "01/01/2020",
      "02/01/2020",
      "03/01/2020",
      "04/01/2020",
      "05/01/2020",
      ...
    ]
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "show": true,
      "type": "value",
      "name": "CAPTURE RATE",
      "nameLocation": "middle",
      "nameRotate": 90,
      "nameGap": 72,
      "nameTextStyle": {
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "fontSize": 11,
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "min": 0,
      "position": "left",
      "offset": 0,
      "inverse": false,
      "axisLabel": {},
      "axisLine": {
        "show": true,
        "onZero": true
      },
      "metric": "CAPTURE_RATE",
      "metricsGroup": "TRAFFIC",
      "formattingType": "PERCENTAGE",
      "yaxisKey": "TRAFFIC__PERCENTAGE"
    },
    {
      "show": true,
      "type": "value",
      "name": "SALES",
      "nameLocation": "middle",
      "nameRotate": -90,
      "nameGap": 72,
      "nameTextStyle": {
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "fontSize": 11,
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "min": 0,
      "position": "right",
      "offset": 0,
      "inverse": false,
      "axisLabel": {},
      "axisLine": {
        "show": true,
        "onZero": true
      },
      "metric": "SALES",
      "metricsGroup": "SALES",
      "formattingType": "FLOAT_NUMBER",
      "yaxisKey": "SALES__FLOAT_NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "show": true,
      "type": "value",
      "name": "TICKETS",
      "nameLocation": "middle",
      "nameRotate": -90,
      "nameGap": 72,
      "nameTextStyle": {
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "fontSize": 11,
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "min": 0,
      "position": "right",
      "offset": 92,
      "inverse": false,
      "axisLabel": {},
      "axisLine": {
        "show": true,
        "onZero": true
      },
      "metric": "TICKETS",
      "metricsGroup": "SALES",
      "formattingType": "NON_FLOAT_NUMBER",
      "yaxisKey": "SALES__NON_FLOAT_NUMBER"
    },
    {
      "show": true,
      "type": "value",
      "name": "C.R.",
      "nameLocation": "middle",
      "nameRotate": -90,
      "nameGap": 72,
      "nameTextStyle": {
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "fontSize": 11,
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "min": 0,
      "position": "right",
      "offset": 184,
      "inverse": false,
      "axisLabel": {},
      "axisLine": {
        "show": true,
        "onZero": true
      },
      "metric": "CONVERSION_RATE",
      "metricsGroup": "SALES",
      "formattingType": "PERCENTAGE",
      "yaxisKey": "SALES__PERCENTAGE"
    }
  ],
  "dataZoom": [],
  "tooltip": {
    "show": true,
    "trigger": "item",
    "axisPointer": {
      "type": "shadow"
    }
  },
  "axisPointer": {},
  "toolbox": {
    "show": true,
    "orient": "horizontal",
    "itemSize": 17,
    "itemGap": 15,
    "showTitle": true,
    "feature": {
      "saveAsImage": {
        "type": "png",
        "name": "tbretail_chart",
        "backgroundColor": "#fff",
        "connectedBackgroundColor": "#fff",
        "excludeComponents": [
          "toolbox"
        ],
        "show": true,
        "title": "Save as image"
      },
      "restore": {
        "show": true,
        "title": "Restore"
      },
      "dataView": {
        "show": false,
        "title": "Data view",
        "readOnly": true,
        "lang": [
          "Data view",
          "Close",
          "Refresh"
        ],
        "backgroundColor": "#fff",
        "textareaColor": "#fff",
        "textareaBorderColor": "#333",
        "textColor": "#000",
        "buttonColor": "#0d47a1",
        "buttonTextColor": "#fff"
      },
      "dataZoom": {
        "show": true,
        "title": {
          "zoom": "Area zooming",
          "back": "Restore area zooming"
        },
        "filterMode": "filter"
      },
      "magicType": {
        "title": "Switch type"
      },
      "brush": {
        "type": "rect",
        "title": "Selection"
      }
    },
    "iconStyle": {
      "borderColor": "#0d47a1",
      "borderWidth": 2
    }
  },
  "brush": {},
  "dataset": {},
  "aria": {},
  "series": [
    {
      "metric": "CAPTURE_RATE",
      "yaxisTarget": {
        "metricsGroup": "TRAFFIC",
        "formattingType": "PERCENTAGE",
        "yaxisKey": "TRAFFIC__PERCENTAGE"
      },
      "yAxisIndex": 0,
      "type": "bar",
      "name": "Capture rate (212.2%)",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 0,
          "tooltip": {}
        },
        ...
      ],
      "label": {
        "show": false,
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": 90,
        "color": "#4f4f4f",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "lineHeight": 12,
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "smooth": true,
      "totalValue": "212.2%"
    },
    {
      "metric": "SALES",
      "yaxisTarget": {
        "metricsGroup": "SALES",
        "formattingType": "FLOAT_NUMBER",
        "yaxisKey": "SALES__FLOAT_NUMBER"
      },
      "yAxisIndex": 1,
      "type": "bar",
      "name": "Sales (12447857.85 €)",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 12608.28,
          "tooltip": {}
        },
        ...
      ],
      "label": {
        "show": false,
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": 90,
        "color": "#4f4f4f",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "lineHeight": 12,
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "smooth": true,
      "totalValue": 12447857.85
    },
    {
      "metric": "TICKETS",
      "yaxisTarget": {
        "metricsGroup": "SALES",
        "formattingType": "NON_FLOAT_NUMBER",
        "yaxisKey": "SALES__NON_FLOAT_NUMBER"
      },
      "yAxisIndex": 2,
      "type": "bar",
      "name": "Tickets (82474)",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 106,
          "tooltip": {}
        },
        ...
      ],
      "label": {
        "show": false,
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": 90,
        "color": "#4f4f4f",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "lineHeight": 12,
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "smooth": true,
      "totalValue": 82474
    },
    {
      "metric": "CONVERSION_RATE",
      "yaxisTarget": {
        "metricsGroup": "SALES",
        "formattingType": "PERCENTAGE",
        "yaxisKey": "SALES__PERCENTAGE"
      },
      "yAxisIndex": 3,
      "type": "bar",
      "name": "C.R. (2.3%)",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 7.61,
          "tooltip": {}
        },
        ...
      ],
      "label": {
        "show": false,
        "position": "top",
        "rotate": 90,
        "color": "#4f4f4f",
        "fontSize": 12,
        "lineHeight": 12,
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "middle"
      },
      "smooth": true,
      "totalValue": "2.3%"
    }
  ],
  "color": [
    "#67B0FE",
    "#8091B4",
    "#56C8EC",
    "#7BC9BA",
    "#B1EC5C",
    "#E5C872",
    "#D28787",
    "#91C283",
    "#B39E75",
    "#D8A1A1",
    "#E4CE58",
    "#9BAE84",
    "#AA8D8D",
    "#8CD49B",
    "#F16363",
    "#99B0D5",
    "#B9BC79",
    "#CF90DD",
    "#FFE760",
    "#7DD197",
    "#AF5D6D",
    "#D49D76",
    "#E7B09A",
    "#CF4E4E"
  ],
  "backgroundColor": "#fff",
  "textStyle": {
    "color": "#000",
    "fontStyle": "normal",
    "fontWeight": "normal",
    "fontFamily": "sans-serif",
    "fontSize": 15,
    "lineHeight": 23
  },
  "animation": true,
  "animationThreshold": 2000,
  "animationDuration": 1000,
  "animationEasing": "cubicOut",
  "animationDelay": 0,
  "animationDurationUpdate": 300,
  "animationEasingUpdate": "cubicOut",
  "animationDelayUpdate": 0,
  "blendMode": "source-over",
  "hoverLayerThreshold": 3000,
  "useUTC": false
}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Edit:

**SOLVED**

**To achieve a fixed yaxis you must set both its `min` and `max` properties.**

Therefore, you can either set them all as fixed or only some of them. It is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found out the solution.

**To achieve a fixed yaxis you must set both its `min` and `max` properties.**

Therefore, you can either set them all as fixed or only some of them. It is completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Echarts is data visualize framework. Data is main block for render visual layer. When you change data — visual layer will changed. Hide series by set transparency color and don't touch data.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyFedorov for your quick response. Maybe this approach of handling the action `action.legend.legendToggleSelect` to handle the `legendselectchanged` event to hide data by setting the series' color with a transparent one could work.

But in the given example, it seems to me that it is achieving fix yaxis without managing events. Moreover, because data is in fact hidden, allowing the rest of bars to occupy all the available space.

In terms of CSS, I'm looking for a display-none-like version, not a visibility-hidden-like one.

Comment: It's not about events. When you toggle series by the legend you have the same result like if you disabled/enabled series directly — axes will redraw anyway. But I see that you have solved this problem and now it is no longer necessary to continue looking for a solution.

Comment: Yes, fortunately I detected that little difference between my options object and the one from the example. Thank you for your clarification, anyway.